# How to use a go.Scattergeo object (Earth) as a plot in order to plot a trajectory in the same plot?

Tags: python, plot, jupyter-notebook, plotly, runge-kutta

I have a code which computes the trajectory of a body considering only the gravitational force acting on it using the runge kutah integrator. I've done it using Matplotlib, and couple days ago I found out Plotly which made me interested to make the same using Plotly instead of Matplotlib because I think it looks better.
This is the result of it:
[image: Orbita ao redor da Terra]

However, I've found out a very beautiful picture I'd like to use in the place of the blue sphere to represent the Earth, like this:

[image: Earth]

This second figure was generated with the following code:

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Scattergeo())
fig.update_geos(projection_type="orthographic")
fig.update_layout(height=300, margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

when I try to plot the trajectory and this Earth made with go.Scattergeo(), I get an error (which I was expecting):

```
Traj = dict()
Traj['Xc'] = DATA[0]
Traj['Yc'] = DATA[1]
Traj['Zc'] = DATA[2]
Traj['Time'] = DATA[3]
Traj = pd.DataFrame(Traj)

Path = go.Scatter3d(x=Traj["Xc"], y=Traj["Yc"], z=Traj["Zc"],marker=dict(size=3),line=dict(color='pink',width=1.5))
Earth = go.Figure(go.Scattergeo())
fig = go.Figure(data=[Earth,Path])
plot(fig)
```

So, how can I use this figure instead of the blue sphere and plot my trajectory?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to be able to rotate the image after plotting the trajectory?

Comment: Yes, I need to rotate the plot for visualization. However, it’d be awesome already if I can at least use this figure.